# MySQL Auto Increment Values After DELETE without WHERE

Tags: mysql, auto-increment, sql-delete

I noticed after running,

```
DELETE FROM tablename
```

My ID (auto increment) values became weird

```
7, 8, 9, 0, 1, 12, 3, 4, 15
```

In this order when I do a,

```
SELECT * FROM tablename
```

I know that the certification guide says that IDs may or may not be reset when DELETE without WHERE is used to empty a table, but what caused the ID sequence to be so weird? I am quite certain that's the order the rows were inserted. Originally before delete I had 6 rows in the table so 7, 8, 9 seems understandable .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in reference to your screen shots:http://img19.imageshack.us/img19/7336/82051321.png and http://img27.imageshack.us/img27/2935/24285862.png

the problem is with your "application code". you're using LOAD DATA INFILE with a file that has windows style (\r\n) line endings, and the default in mysql unless you specify otherwise is unix style (\n).

to see what i mean, try this:

```
mysql> load data infile 'data.txt' into table testDel (val);
Query OK, 6 rows affected (0.01 sec)
Records: 6  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> select * from testDel;
+----+----------------+
| id | val            |
+----+----------------+
 | 7 | hello world 1
 | 8 | hello world 2
 | 9 | hello world 3
 | 0 | hello world 4
 | 1 | hello world 5
| 12 | hello world 6  |
+----+----------------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select id, hex(val) from testDel;
+----+------------------------------+
| id | hex(val)                     |
+----+------------------------------+
|  7 | 68656C6C6F20776F726C6420310D |
|  8 | 68656C6C6F20776F726C6420320D |
|  9 | 68656C6C6F20776F726C6420330D |
| 10 | 68656C6C6F20776F726C6420340D |
| 11 | 68656C6C6F20776F726C6420350D |
| 12 | 68656C6C6F20776F726C642036   |
+----+------------------------------+
6 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

what's happening is the \r is clobbering the display of your values. did you notice how your tables "walls" don't line up? this should be a hint that something is wrong with the display, as evidenced by the query with hex(val) where the "walls" do line up.

to fix the import, you have to specify the line endings in the file:

```
mysql> load data infile 'data.txt' into table testDel lines terminated by '\r\n' (val);
Query OK, 6 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 6  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> select * from testDel;
+----+---------------+
| id | val           |
+----+---------------+
| 13 | hello world 1 |
| 14 | hello world 2 |
| 15 | hello world 3 |
| 16 | hello world 4 |
| 17 | hello world 5 |
| 18 | hello world 6 |
+----+---------------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: oh thanks. but i will understand why \r may affect the display but ids ... ?

Comment: the point of my example was to show you that the data is not wrong. the \r is just simply screwing up the formatting. in fact, if you had been using a different tool such as phpmyadmin, you wouldn't have even noticed this problem.

Answer (score 3):

There is absolutely no semblence or guarantee of order in a database without an `order by` clause. This has to do with how the records are stored--they are not stored in sequence of anything. The database often optimizes how it stores the data based on clustered indices, but each database stores data a bit differently.

You should never, ever, ever think that you will have a repeatable order *unless* you use the `order by` clause.

So, it appears that your IDs got reclaimed. There's absolutely nothing weird about that order--you essentially selected a pseudo-random ordering in the first place.

Comment: i undertstand "There is absolutely no semblence or guarantee of order in a database without an order by clause" but i expected the order of which the IDs are reused to be ascending? i thought that the order will be random only upon retrieval (because its stored "*randomly*")? even when IDs are reused its random? and usually IDs dont use 0?

Comment: I don't know when the deletes happened or what they deleted, so that doesn't look weird to me at all. And if the table is set up as `AUTO_INCREMENT=0`, then 0 will come into play.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of DELETE FROM you should try

```
TRUNCATE tablename
```

I believe this will also reset the sequence for ID.

Comment: That's `truncate table tablename`, and sweet Lord, man, that's a nuclear option. It's not transactional, and you can't roll it back if you have an "Oh, wait!" moment. Be very, very careful with that button.

Comment: "truncate table tablename" and "truncate tablename" both work. And in this case you don't care about transactions. I simply provide a way to reset the ID sequence of a table. I agree that you shouldn't use this in production code.

Comment: i understand what truncate does. i am just wondering why when i *test* using delete the order becomes so wierd. i also understand that if i do not use order by the sequence is not guaranteed but at least i expected the order of IDs to be as when they are inserted.

Answer (score 0):

there's something going on here besides just DELETE, then 10 simple INSERT, then a simple SELECT. you have a 0 in your ID list, which means something somewhere is specifying values for your auto_increment column.

i would check your application code.

if that's not it, the you need to come up with a specific set of steps (including a CREATE TABLE) that shows how this problem can be reproduced.

Comment: this is what i did, an image of the cmd http://img19.imageshack.us/img19/7336/82051321.png. basically i did a load data infile. insert dont seem to trigger this ... the data file http://img27.imageshack.us/img27/2935/24285862.png